# How do I redirect from http:// to https:// to https://www without breaking other subdomains that aren't www?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, http-redirect

**The environment:**

Wordpress running on a Docker container which is built up a testing pipeline, first into dev (`https://dev.example.com`), then stage (`https://stage.example.com`), then finally into production (`https://www.example.com`).

Note that both Dev and Stage do *not* have the "www" subdomain but production does.

**The problem:**

For security reasons, I have to set up an extra redirect. Currently, when a user enters our site without SSL (ie, `http://example.com`) they are redirected to the secured subdomain (ie, `https://www.example.com`).

However, for security, they need to hit `https://example.com` *before* being redirected to the secured subdomain. Such as:

1) `http://example.com` ->

2) `https://example.com` ->

3) `https://www.example.com`

We must have www as the final result and we must have the extra redirect (there's no wiggle room, sadly).

**Now, where I'm getting stuck is with this redirect and the dev/stage sites.**

I can get production redirecting from `http://example.com` -> `https://example.com` -> `https://www.example.com` with the code below:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
# ensure https
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example.com$
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com [L,R=301]

# ensure www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

**But when this code is moved into dev/stage they 502 to death.**

I've tried using the code below to only redirect to www when the server is not www or dev or stage but then the redirect from `http://example.com` to `https://example.com` fails!

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
# ensure https
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example.com$
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com [L,R=301]

# ensure www only if not dev/stage
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|dev|stage)\.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Please help! I know using so many redirects is over the top but they are the requirements I've been given and I can't change them.

Any help is really appreciated, I've looked at many other answers here and they have helped but I cannot get past the dev/stage redirect failing. I'm stuck!

---

**My full htaccess file:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

 RewriteEngine On
 # ensure https
 RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
 RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (^|\.)example\.com$
 RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=302]

 # ensure www.
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|corp-dev|corp-stage)\.example\.com$
 RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=302]

# link Redirection

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^health\.html$ "/health.html" [END]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**What ended up solving this issue for me:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
  RewriteRule (.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$
  RewriteRule (.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dev.example.com$
  RewriteRule (.*)$ https://dev.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^stage.example.com$
  RewriteRule (.*)$ https://stage.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

My WordPress site had Site URL under the General Settings tab set to `https://www.example.com` and this was causing a bunch of looping with the other solutions.

This didn't work for me due to the setting I mentioned but I'll post another solution I tried on the off chance it will help someone else:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
# Redirect HTTP to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://example.com/$1 [R,L]

# Redirect example.com to www.example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt is nearly fine, I just made some trivial adjustments:

```
RewriteEngine On
# ensure https
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (^|\.)example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301]

# ensure www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|dev|stage)\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301]
```

In general it is a good idea to start testing using a 302 redirection and only change that to a 301 once things are really working. That way you prevent caching issues while testing.

This rule will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

Comment: Thank you for this!  I've tried your suggestion and I'm getting this error:
`AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error.`
It's a different error than before but I still can't get it to work.

Comment: EDIT: I've tried removing everything but a basic health check from my htaccess and finally got the redirect to stop erroring out. However, the URL is redirecting like this: `https://www.example.com/https://example.com/`

Comment: There must be some other rule involved here. Above rule set does not implement an endless rewriting loop.

Comment: Yes, there must be something I'm missing. I'm primarily front-end and have minimal experience with Apache. I added my full htaccess file at the very bottom of my original post.